# How to setup p2p connection in coradova for android and ios?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, real-time, webrtc

I want a p2p communication between mobile phones without a server(and possibly with no internet). I have seen [cordova-httpd](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-httpd) But looking for a more real time communication. If I can host a websocket server and others connect, it would be ideal.

Any other frameworks, architectures technologies to archive this?

Answer (score 0):

This question might be too broad and open for interpretation.  The answers you may get will be based on opinion, rather then helpful solutions based on a specific technical problem.

Generally speaking, I'd use local storage to store/queue messages that get sent & received. That way I am not dependent upon the internet or connectivity.  I'd then have a separate service or function that runs when connectivity is present.  That way your user can continue to send messages, etc. while not having internet connectivity.  Basically, use local storage to queue up messages until you have connectivity. This is just me trying to be helpful - just my 2 cents.

Comment: Im interested in real time communication. data communication between clients p2p without a server. Say a wifi network which doesnt have internet, but still the mobile phones connected can talk to each other.